# CoreBluetooth between two iOS apps

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am trying to get started with bluetooth on `iOS`, in order to make two neighbouring devices communicate using `CoreBluetooth`.
On one device an app is running playing the role of peripheral and on the other device another app is running playing the role of central.

Here is the relevant code for the two apps.

The peripheral app:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {
    let serviceOne_UUID = CBUUID(string:"FB694B90-F49E-4597-8306-171BBA78F846"),
    svcOneChrcOne_UUID = CBUUID(string:"EB6727C4-F184-497A-A656-76B0CDAC633A")
    var cbPerifMngr:CBPeripheralManager!, mutaSRVC:CBMutableService!,
    svcOneCharacOne:CBMutableCharacteristic!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cbPerifMngr = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }


    // CBPeripheralManagerDelegate protocol implementation.

    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            mutaSRVC = CBMutableService(type: serviceOne_UUID, primary: true)
            svcOneCharacOne = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: svcOneChrcOne_UUID,
                                                      properties:  [.read, .notify], 
                                                      value: nil, permissions: .readable)
            mutaSRVC.characteristics = [svcOneCharacOne]
            cbPerifMngr?.add(mutaSRVC)
        }
    }


    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        } else {
            cbPerifMngr.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:service.uuid])
        }
    }


    func peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, error: Error?) {
        if error != nil {
            print("Error in \(#function) :\n\(error!)")
        }
    }
}
```

The central app:

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController,CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    var cbCenterMngr:CBCentralManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        cbCenterMngr = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }


    // CBCentralManagerDelegate protocol implementation.

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        print(#function)
        if central.state == .poweredOn {
            print("\(#function) poweredOn")
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [CBUUID(string:"FB694B90-F49E-4597-8306-171BBA78F846")],
                                       options: nil)
        }
    }


    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, 
                        didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, 
                        advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print(#function)
    }


    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```

At this point, when I run both apps at the same time, I do not see anything happening showing that some kind of connection is taking place. Can anybody tell me if I need to look in a particular place or if the code above is simply wrong and nothing will happen? In which case some advice or hint would be highly appreciated.

P.S.
After trying again, I noticed this error in the logging console of the peripheral app:

```
peripheralManager(_:didAdd:error:)
peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_:error:)
Error in peripheralManagerDidStartAdvertising(_:error:) :
Error Domain=CBErrorDomain Code=1 "One or more parameters were invalid." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=One or more parameters were invalid.}
```

Comment: `mutaSRVC` and `svcOneCharacOne` need to be properties, not local variables.

Comment: Thanks, that is actually the way it is in my code. For some reason I made a mistake when making the post. I fixed it.